# Enzyme basic test using shallow errors with 'Target is not a DOM element'

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying an incredibly basic test using `shallow`. I was under the impression that `shallow` requires zero dependencies outside of the component itself, but I hit this error:

```
 FAIL  src/test/app/AppHeader/buttons/LogoButton.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

      16 |   })
      17 | }
    > 18 | 
      19 | ReactDOM.render(
      20 |   <Provider store={store}>
      21 |     <Router history={history}>

      at invariant (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:55:15)
```

My code for the test is:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import LogoButton from 'components/app/AppHeader/buttons/LogoButton'

describe('test of initial load', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <LogoButton />
        )
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

and my `index.tsx` (which the location of the error) is this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import registerServiceWorker from 'registerServiceWorker'
import store from 'redux/Store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Root from 'routes/Root'

export const history = createHashHistory()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'store', {
    get: () => store.getState()
  })
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Root />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
)
registerServiceWorker()
```

I believe the fact that I'm using TypeScript is irrelevant to my issue. I honestly have no idea what's wrong. On a general level, I could see why this would happen if I used `mount`, but why with `shallow`? Why would this test run into issues with my code in `index.tsx`?

```
class LogoButton extends React.Component<Props> {
    handleReset = async () => {
        history.push('/')
        this.props.setUIElementStatus({
            uiElement: UI_ELEMENTS.UI_SEARCH_BAR, show: false
        })
        this.props.setSearchInputValue({ text: '' })
    }

    render() {
        const { titleFilled, titleBlank } = this.props.classes
        const titleClass = this.props.uiStatus.searchBar ? titleFilled : titleBlank
        const navButtonProps = {
            onClick: this.handleReset,
            className: titleClass,
            variant: 'flat' as 'flat',
            disableFocusRipple: true,
            disableRipple: true
        }
        return (
            <Button {...navButtonProps}>
                Tansaki
            </Button>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: storeTypes.Store) => {
    const { uiStatus } = state
    return { uiStatus }
}

const { setSearchInputValue } = InputActions
const { setUIElementStatus } = UiActions

const mapDispatchToProps = { setSearchInputValue, setUIElementStatus }

export default withStyles(styles)(connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(LogoButton))
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of the LogoButton? It seems that for some reason, the ReactDOM.render code is being called - enzyme shallow won't have any chance with that one.

Comment: @flq Updated. I took out all the imports, material-ui styles, and typescript interfaces/types. It feels like a perfectly normal component.

Comment: Try also exporting the LogoButton unconnected and use that for your test - does it still behave odd?

Comment: @flq Totally my fault. As brian stated in the answer, I was creating and exporting my `history` in `index.tsx` and that was the origin of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

That error means that `index.tsx` is accidentally getting imported into `LogoButton.test.tsx`.

### Solution

Trace back the `import` statements starting in `LogoButton.test.tsx` until you find where `index.tsx` is accidentally getting imported and fix or remove that `import` statement.

### Details

If `index.tsx` ever gets imported during a test then it will immediately run `ReactDOM.render`.  In this case that statement is trying to render a component into the `root` element.

The default test environment for `Jest` is `jsdom` which provides a browser-like environment but the `document` provided by `jsdom` is empty by default meaning that `document.getElementById('root')` will return `null`.  When `ReactDOM.render` tries to render into `null` it throws the error seen above.

Comment: I was creating and exporting my `history` in `index.tsx` and that was the origin of the problem. Thank you.